# Float align the background to the right in ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

How to align the background image to the right?
I try to make an image as a background aligned to the right
i tried:

```
position: 'absolute', right: 0,
justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
alignSelf: 'flex-end',
```

But nothing works

```
<ImageBackground source={getImage(item.image)} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} 
                    imageStyle={{width: '50%', height: '50%'}}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
        printing and typesetting industry.</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you post an image of what you are looking to do, that might get you some answers.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I want to add a background to a text but i want the background to fill only the right side of the view.
the text should start from the left and the image in the right.
i think ImageBackground won't help me here, so i will use IMAGE and position.